# Server-edit Automatically When Buffer is Killed

Tags: emacsclient, server

I'm considering using emacs as a server (using `(server-start)`) but I do not want to use `C-x #` to kill buffers. I've heard of the `-n` option for emacsclient, but I'm concerned that it may cause unwanted behavior when other programs use emacsclient. I've thought about using this:

```
(add-hook kill-buffer-hook server-edit)
```

Would this work?

Comment: You'd need to quote things: `(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'server-edit)` - but it's worth trying. If it doesn't work, you can remove the function from the hook using `remove-hook` and get back to where you where.

Comment: I don't see any benefit to adding `server-edit` to `kill-buffer-hook`. It would do some potentially unwanted buffer switching whenever you kill a buffer, but otherwise wouldn't change what happens when you kill a buffer. You can kill a buffer normally even if it's serving a client. You get a confirmation prompt; if you want to get rid of the prompt, doing something after that prompt won't help. Please clarify your question: what is your current workflow, which part bothers you, and how do you want Emacs to react differently?

Comment: Please clarify what is the problem you have with `C-x #` exactly as well as which uses of `emacsclient` you're concerned with.

Comment: I guess I could get used to `C-x #`, but it is inconvenient, and I am likely to accidentally close buffers in other ways very frequently before I get used to it. For example, I have already built up muscle memory for `z x` (I use evil-mode). I may be wrong, but I would guess that programs such as git, emacs anywhere, etc. would see emacsclient close and assume I am done editing before I have even begun if I used the `-n` flag, recording the wrong information.